# Sizing matrices with fractions

Tags: spacing

I was trying to write the difference of two matrices as follows:

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\[2ex]
    0 \\[2ex]
    0
  \end{bmatrix}
  - 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{1}{2} \\[2ex]
    \dfrac{1}{2} \\[2ex]
    \dfrac{1}{2}
  \end{bmatrix}
  = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{1}{2} \\[2ex]
    -\dfrac{1}{2} \\[2ex]
    -\dfrac{1}{2}
  \end{bmatrix}$$
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I just wanted to know how to make the <1, 0, 0> matrix the same size as the others, or any better solution to displaying this expression would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an automatic alignment throughout the arrays (without using `\vphantom`), you can use `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`. You need at least v. 5.15 (2021-04-25).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

$A = \begin{NiceArray}{[c]c[c]c[c]}[cell-space-limits=2pt]
1 &   & \frac{1}{2} &   & \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & - & \frac{1}{2} & = & -\frac{1}{2} \\
0 &   & \frac{1}{2} &   & -\frac{1}{2} 
\end{NiceArray}$
 
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 3):

You can add some `\vphantom`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{bmatrix}
    \vphantom{\frac{1}{2}}1 \\[2ex]
    \vphantom{\frac{1}{2}}0 \\[2ex]
    \vphantom{\frac{1}{2}}0
  \end{bmatrix}
  - 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2} \\[2ex]
    \frac{1}{2} \\[2ex]
    \frac{1}{2}
  \end{bmatrix}
  = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2} \\[2ex]
    -\frac{1}{2} \\[2ex]
    -\frac{1}{2}
  \end{bmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 3):

I have use an old package named spalign...My recommendation is not to use `\dfrac` because  you will have the original your screenshot. :-)
After I have put several `\\` to have blank spaces...I not think that there is an option in this package for the rows/columns. You can use for all the vectors also `\spalignvector` instead of `\spalignmat`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{spalign}
\begin{document}
\[ \spaligndelims{[}{]} \spalignmat{1\\; 0\\; 0} - \spalignmat{\frac{1}{2}\\; \frac{1}{2}\\; \frac{1}{2}}=\spalignvector[r]{\frac{1}{2}\\ -\frac{1}{2}\\ -\frac{1}{2}}\]
\[ \spaligndelims{[}{]} \spalignmat{1; 0; 0} - \spalignmat{\frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{2}}=\spalignvector[c]{\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2}}\]
\[ \spaligndelims{[}{]} \spalignmat{1\\; 0\\; 0} - \spalignmat{\frac{1}{2}\\; \frac{1}{2}\\; \frac{1}{2}}=\spalignvector[c]{\frac{1}{2}\\ -\frac{1}{2}\\ -\frac{1}{2}}\]
\end{document}
```

You can see that I have used `\spalignvector`[`l` or `c` or `r`] to have centered (c) the elements of the vector.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Plain TeX solution:

```
$$
  \def\mymatrix#1{\left[\matrix{#1}\right]}
  \normalbaselineskip=15pt
  \mymatrix{1\cr 0\cr 0} - \mymatrix{1\over2\cr 1\over2\cr 1\over2} =
                           \mymatrix{1\over2\cr -{1\over2}\cr -{1\over2}}
$$
\bye
```

Comment: Very nice to see a plain TeX solution!